# How to edit the text on the checkout in Magento (step 4. Payment Information)

Tags: checkout, paypal, payment, edit

How do I edit the text found in this box?
The company that set up our website set it up with PayPal Standard Payments - where if the customer wants to pay by credit or debit card they go to PayPal's website.
PayPal are phasing out the 'Guest Checkout' facility on this so only half our customers are getting the option to pay via credit or debit card.

I want to flick it over to PayPal Website Payments Pro (Hosted Solution) but need to remove the visa mastercard logo they added in plus the small sentence.

[image: Screenshot from checkout displaying the parts I would like to edit.]

Comment: have you use which Payment method you have select? open in Magento backend. and change the text or you can you template path hint and find the file

Comment: This text would be coming from paypal payment module...I dont have access to code right now..but paypal standar module files you will get some hint

Comment: Thanks Keyul, I never knew there was such thing as template path hint - very handy.
The code in the mark.phtml file is where the logo is found, but I cannot see where the 2 additional logos were added in.
I do not understand this
<img src="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getPaymentAcceptanceMarkSrc())?>"

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline translations as well. Take a look at:

[inline translation](http://www.neevtech.com/blog/2011/09/03/easily-change-default-magento-text-and-labels/)

Or by editing template:
[Theme Text Editor](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-the-theme-text-editor)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have just used inline translation to remove the sentence I didn't want, but cannot see any way to get rid of the 2 extra logos after the PayPal logo.

Comment: Logo is taken from PayPal site.Try to experiment with your PayPal settings.